# spark execution core assign to tasks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, execution

In general each core in system execute one task in spark submit. How one core can be share by multiple tasks execute by spark submit? Means i am executing 10 Threads in spark submit . But I can able to execute 4 tasks at a time ,after 4 task complete next 4 starts. **How I can start execute 10 tasks at once by spark submit ?**

Comment: You might want to modify `spark.default.parallelism`in your spark conf. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior